# Override gem method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to let users add interests -TV shows in this case-, and to make sure they type a correct tv show, I'm going to search imdb first and let them select one of the returning titles.

I found this gem https://github.com/ariejan/imdb which is doing almost what I need. If I search for "The vampire diaries", it will return it and 200 extra matches.

I went through the gem and I found that he does the querying part here https://github.com/ariejan/imdb/blob/master/lib/imdb/search.rb.

```
   def self.query(query)
      open("http://akas.imdb.com/find?q=#{CGI.escape(query)};s=tt")
   end
```

That query basically uses this link http://akas.imdb.com/find?q= and returns everything that can find given the input - movies, tv shows, episodes. Now I found a more advanced query which uses `type` and some other params. So I could actually return only 4 results in that case instead of 250. All I have to do is to replace that query with http://www.imdb.com/search/title?title=The%20Vampire%20Diaries&title_type=tv_series.

How do I override that search method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can re-open the class to override the method:

```
class Imdb::Search
  def self.query(query)
    # your custom logic here
  end
end
```

Note that you can call `super(query)` in your version to get the result of the original.

Comment: Thanks for answering. In which folder should I put that file?

Comment: It doesn't matter since constants like classes are shared between files. Just make sure to add it before you call the Imdb query.

Comment: I would put it in a new file in `config/initializers`.

Comment: @maxple I put it inside the tv shows controller. I will put another one for the movies controller.

Comment: @BogdanDaniel that won't work. You cannot define the same method in multiple places and have them both be called _unless_ you put `super` in there. Why not patch it one time (somewhere in `config/initializers/` as jbarr recommends) but alter it so it takes an additional argument (the url)?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, but for some reason I get an extra null movie object for each actual title. I can t find where to look to solve that.

Comment: you should use `byebug` and put a debugger call in there.

Comment: I think it s just a matter of html sytnax. I'm inspecting both pages now.

Comment: Yeah, they are so much different. I will just write one myself and parse html only for the elements that I need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use class_eval and put it in a decorators folder

```
app/decorators/imdb/search_decorator.rb

class Imdb::Search.class_eval do
  def self.query(query)
  end
end
```